# ¿En javaScript cómo puedo mandar a llamar un array usando un atributo con el nombre como valor?

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo varios arrays, pero quiero mandar a llamar uno por uno, como se lo pida de forma dinamica utilizando un atributo name en un div.

```
var cptt = ['uno', 'dos']

var eso = [];

var gtptt = []

var sis = []

var silt = [];
```

[image: Asi aparece cuando lo escribo de forma manual y reconoce el array]

Comment: Lenguaje de programacion?

Comment: javascript, quiero mandar a llamar un array a travez de un atributo que tiene el nombre de la funcion

Comment: vas a tener que usar un gran if... o meter esos array dentro de un diccionario

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar un poco más lo que necesitas? Gracias.